# Odoo v11, Error: "res.users, Operation: read None", while creating a new user and assign to new company

Tags: odoo, crm, erp, odoo-11

I have a problem creating a new user on Odoo and assign to a company that I created v. 11.

First on companies I created a new company name "XXXX".

Then I created a new user "YYY" and on the multicompany field I assigned on "allowed companies" the company "XXXX", and on "Current Company" I assigned the company "XXXX".
The problem is that when i try to save the new user created I received this error:

"Error while validating constraint

The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.

(Document type: res.users, Operation: read)
None "

The only way i can save the new user is by selecting on the field "Allowed Companies" the default company created from the system.

Is there something I did wrong while creating the new company "XXXX" or is there some relation and/or rights that are particular important between user and company?

Comment: I haven't get any error while creating new user and assigning new company to it. Check your access right configuration of admin may be issue is related to that.

Comment: @RosMyster Please download the latest build form the http://nightly.odoo.com/ and use it from your end